# Could not determine type for at table for columns

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, setter, getter

I have a class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

}

// -----------------------------------

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProductPrice {

    @Id
    public Long getId() {
        return product.getId();
    }

    @OneToOne
    private Product product;

    @Column(precision = 38, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal price;

}
```

I got an error

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.myapps.model.Product, at table: product_price, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(product)]
```

As you can see, i am using id from Product class as an id of ProductPrice class. Can we do something like that? If it can, it would be great. But if cannot, i will use regular Long type as an id of ProductPrice. Please give me an advice. Thanks

Comment: If it is OneToOne why not storing the price in the same product table? Each join costs with performance

Comment: You were right. I might have to consider your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to declare the column for the attribute product.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProductPrice {

     @Id
     public Long getId() {
         return product.getId();
     }

     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID", unique= true, nullable=true, insertable=true, updatable=true)  
     private Product product;

     @Column(precision = 38, scale = 2)
     private BigDecimal price;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it still not solved. I try every combination from your suggestion. I change name PRODUCT_ID, product_id, id but still have not work.

Comment: @Mirza you are mapping 2 tables, product and product_price, then in product_price, you should have a FK to product. and thats the column name you have to use into the JoinColumn annotation